# Is there a way to search for help page with partial keywords in python or jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, search, jupyter, keyword

I am not free to googling in a limited internet access environment. I can't memorize all the functions, so I need a way to search help page with a partial content from the help page

situation 1)
If I'm not sure if it's `df.value_counts()` or `df_value_count()`, So, is there any other way than to paste `help(df)` the output into a text editor and search it?

situation 2)
If I say that I do not completely know the function name of kurtosis(), should I check all the functions one by one after using help(df)?

In other words, in Unix environments, I can search the man page using pipe to less and feed that a search term, as follows

```
man 1 find | less -p ' -type'
```

I need a similar approach.

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jupyter auto completion with tab

You can use also another ide like pycharm which is more complete to help in coding, but have less visualisation than jupyter

[Jupyter Shortcuts](https://cheatography.com/weidadeyue/cheat-sheets/jupyter-notebook/)

Or use [Hinterland Extension](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html)

Answer (score 0):

*So, is there any other way than to paste `help(df)` the output into a text editor and search it?*

`pydoc` built-in module could be used to create HTML page with documentation, example usage:

```
import pandas as pd
import pydoc
pydoc.writedoc(pd.DataFrame)
```

output

```
wrote DataFrame.html
```

Said file do appear in current working directory and could be viewed using any webbrowser, as it is *local* it is not affected by *limited internet access environment*. You might also use `pydoc` for running local help server, just do in terminal

```
python -m pydoc -b
```

You might also use `dir` built-in function to see what is available in given object, for example

```
import math
print(dir(math))
```

output

```
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'comb', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'dist', 'e', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 'hypot', 'inf', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'isqrt', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'log2', 'modf', 'nan', 'perm', 'pi', 'pow', 'prod', 'radians', 'remainder', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'tau', 'trunc']
```

Note that `dir` does return `list` of `str`s, so it could be filtered using `str` methods for example

```
import math
print([i for i in dir(math) if i.startswith("is")])
```

output

```
['isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'isqrt']
```